# resource for overall weighted mark or assignment category can't find

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

I have looked in the various resources for coursework and cannot find the specific categories. The workType will just return that it is an assignment, but no category that I have set up for that assignment to assign grades into.

Also I have tried to check to see if there is a stored value for the overall weighted grade for each student, but cannot find this entry either. This may be autogenerated based on category/grade calculations and put into each slot on page loadup.

Any help with these would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this Issue Tracker [post](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133254580), there is no direct function to retrieve the average grade for each student. As you can read in the Google's reply, this can be done by programming with the API.

In this case, it consists in iterating over the [courseWork.studentSubmissions](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list?). The response returns, beside others, the `studentSubmissions` resource which is grouped into each assignement and their respective `submissionHistory`.

You have to get each `assignedGrade` and do the average for each student. For example:

```
  var courseWorks = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.list(courseId);
  var courseWorkIds = [], list_Grades = [];

  var list_Students = Classroom.Courses.Students.list(courseId).students;
  var list_Topics = Classroom.Courses.Topics.list(courseId).topic;

  for (var i = 0; i < courseWorks.courseWork.length; i++){

    courseWorkIds.push(courseWorks.courseWork[i].id);  

    var topicId = courseWorks.courseWork[i].topicId;
    getSubmissions(courseId, courseWorks.courseWork[i].id, list_Grades, topicId);

  }
 getAverage(list_Grades, list_Students, list_Topics);
}  

function getAverage(list_Grades, list_Students, list_Topics){

  for (var r = 0; r < list_Students.length; r++){

    Logger.log("===================================");
    Logger.log("Student: " + list_Students[r].userId);
    Logger.log("===================================");
    for (var s = 0; s < list_Topics.length; s++){
      var total = 0;
      var counter = 0;
      Logger.log("Topic: " + list_Topics[s].name);

      for (var t = 0; t < list_Grades.length; t++){

        if (list_Topics[s].topicId == list_Grades[t].topicId && list_Students[r].userId == list_Grades[t].studentId){

          total += list_Grades[t].grade;
          counter++;
        }

      }
      Logger.log("Average: " + (total / counter));
    }
  }
}

function getSubmissions(courseId, courseWorkId, list_Grades, topicId){

  var list_submissions = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list(courseId, courseWorkId).studentSubmissions;

  for (var j = 0; j < list_submissions.length; j++){

    var subs = Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.get(courseId, courseWorkId, list_submissions[j].id);

    list_Grades.push(new Grades(topicId, subs.assignedGrade, subs.userId));

  }
}

function Grades(topicId, grade, studentId){
  this.topicId = topicId;
  this.grade = grade;
  this.studentId = studentId;

}
```

With the Id of the student you can [get](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.students/get?) the rest of the information, like the name or the email address.

You will also need to [authorize](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/scopes) the scopes: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.coursework.students`
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.topics.readonly`
`https://www.googleapis.com/auth/classroom.rosters`

**References:**

- [Courses](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses)
- [CourseWork](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork)
- [StudentSubmissions](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions)

> **Note:** This generates the Average grade for each Student and Topic.

Comment: I thank you for your prompt response. I do indeed need to get the categories and hopefully as well as the weighting to automate the process. I can retrieve, log and publish everything already except for the assigned category and weighted percentage that is assigned by the user to that grade category to be able to output a proper calculated weighted mark. Any help in this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, I changed the code in order to fit the Topic requirement. Check if it's useful to you.

Comment: The script works for 12 entries, but there are many more. I am unsure as to why it only lists these 12.

Comment: I am unsure as to why it only lists these 12.  The topic ID simply returns the title of the assignment itself not the category it is in. My marks in google classroom are divided up into 8 different categories with multiple entries in each category.  I am also unsure at the marks now being produced beside these topic entries such as 3.6665 do not match the mark, nor the average of all the grades for that assignment topic. I need the assigned category and % value for each assignment/topicID so I can group those assignments together, figure that average and then multiply by the indicated %.

Comment: They may have simply not made this accessible to developers in a resource that we have access to??

Comment: I found this issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123557207#comment2 and left a comment for them asking for an update on the status